# Function triggered multiple times when modal close button is clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal below and when I open and close it say 4 times, the function in the modal will also be triggered 4 times too. Meaning during the 4th time I opened it and when I pressed the `Mint button` (`#final-mint-btn`) in the modal, the `console.log("Test");` in `function mintErc20Token` is called 4 times.

How come? I've spent 2 hours debugging but couldn't get why.

Below is the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="token-minting-modal" data-backdrop="false" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="minting-modal-label">How many to mint?</h5>
      </div>
        <form>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="minting-modal-msg" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="token-amount">
                        Amount:
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="token_amount" id="token-amount" placeholder="1000" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="minting-results">
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="minting-modal-close-btn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="final-mint-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Mint</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the button that triggers the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="mint-token-btn" onclick="mintErc20Token('0x3b757', '0x867c099011', '968');">Mint Tokens</button>
```

This is the `function mintErc20Token` to be called in the modal.

```
async function mintErc20Token( senderWallet, contractAddress, postId ) {
    
    let tokenAmount = '';
    
    //Display the modal pop-up
    jQuery("#token-minting-modal").modal("show");
    jQuery("#token-minting-modal").appendTo("body");
    //jQuery("#mint-token-btn").attr("disabled");
    jQuery("#minting-results").hide();
    jQuery('#token-minting-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        jQuery('form').trigger('reset'); // to reset the form
    })
    
    jQuery('#final-mint-btn').click( async function() {
        ...

        //DEBUG
        console.log("Test");
        
    });
}
```

Comment: When you add event handlers **inside** another event handler, they pile up. Calling jQuery `.on()` does not remove other event handlers, even for the same event.

Comment: @Pointy. Ok, do you have any idea how to prevent them from piling up? Like how can I trigger something in a modal?

Comment: @Pointy I think I solved it by doing this - `jQuery('#final-mint-btn').off("click").click( async function() {`. Is this correct? I'm a newbie btw.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing...

```
jQuery('#final-mint-btn').click( async function() {
```

with...

```
jQuery('#final-mint-btn').off("click").click( async function() {
```